# Django Signup form validation

Tags: django, forms, unit-testing, validation

I have signup form in django which has only 3 fields(username, password and confirm password) created using default userCreationForm with default input fields validations.[Signuppage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvLcK.png)

Now I want to write test case for those validation logic in picture. How to write it? I have done basic tests which are as follows:
**tests.py**

```
class SignUpPageTests(TestCase):
username = 'sampleuser'
email = 'sampleuser@email.com'

def test_signupStatusCheck(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/accounts/signup/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

def test_signupViewName(self):
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('signup'))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

def test_signupViewFile(self):
    resp = self.client.get(reverse('signup'))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(resp,'signup.html')

def test_signupFormTest(self):
    self.newuser = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
        self.username,self.email
    )
    self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.all().count(),1)
    self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.all()                                                                               
    [0].username,self.username)        
    self.assertEqual(get_user_model().objects.all()[0].email,self.email)
```

**Signup.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock title %} 
{% block content %}
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserCreationForm` is part of the Django Core, which means it is [already tested](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.2/tests/auth_tests/test_forms.py#L42). There are already test cases to make sure the length validators, common password, numeric password, etc. is working. So, you don't have to test it twice.

A different thing would be *testing if your application is configured to use those password validators*.

Something like that:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.conf import settings

class SettingsTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.validators = settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS

    def test_has_common_password_validator(self):
        has_validator = False
        for validator in self.validators:
            if validator['NAME'] == 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator':
                has_validator = True
                break
        self.assertTrue(has_validator)
```